# psql says password is incorrect for user that does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to create a database and each time I run the `createdb [databasename]`, and enter the "incorrect" password, command I get the following error, `createdb: error: could not connect to database template1: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "[username]"`.

However, the user that says the authentication has failed for doesn't exist. I can run `psql -U postgres` and enter the password I provided previously and log in just fine. Once logged in as Postgres user I run `\du` and only see the Postgres user in the table. Any reason this would be happening? I uninstalled and reinstalled and still have the same issue. Why is the default user something other than the original postgres user?

Here is the result of the `\du` command

```
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
```

Comment: I have even tried logging in as the postgres user and running `postgres=# ALTER USER [failedUser] PASSWORD '[newPassword]';` But, once I run that command I get the message ```ERROR:  role "[failedUser]" does not exist```.

Comment: Add `-U postgres` to your createdb line.

Comment: User defaults to the OS username. So unless you are logged in as postgres you will get another username which might or might not be present in your database.

Answer (score 0):

The error message does not tell you the exact reason why authentication failed on purpose, to give attackers as little information as possible.

The cause of your problem might be that your username contains upper case letters on the operating system, but you created the database user without using double quotes, so that the upper case letters got translated to lower case.

If you want more than guessing, you have to tell us the exact command line and the output from `\du`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I had to add the username from my OS because that is what Postgresql defaults to, as well as add a DB with the same name.